# add Web form Controls to Windows Forms

Tags: asp.net, winforms, aspxgridview

I have created a gridview in a web form and I need to create a windows form to display the gridview's output, the number of red colors and green colors in the gridview. Is it possible to draw a hidden web form gridview into a Windows form application? I have tried to add it programmatically by removing ".net Client profile" from Properties, but when I run the code, it gives error "Object not set to reference of instance" at the line "grdWebForm.DataBind();".

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully overcome the "Object not set to reference of instance" error.
put grd.AllowPaging=false;
and the error doesn't come